# Use newer Visual Studio Version with an older MFC Version?

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

From my understanding Visual Studio 2005 always uses MFC8 automaticly, VS2008 MFC9 and VS2010 the MFC10.

Can use a newer Visual Studio Version and still link to an older MFC Version?

I searched the options and the project settings all over but I could not find any option about the MFC.

Comment: You'll have to tinker with the search paths for include and library files so the old version is found first.  Avoid the wizards.

Answer (score 1):

VS2010 apparently (I don't have it, so I haven't tried it) has the ability to use both VS2008 and VS2010 toolsets to build the applications, provided they are both installed in the machine.

More [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx)

I would expect Visual Studio 11 to have the same ability, but who knows...