# Use an older version of MFC with a newer version of Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012 (v11) which is using a version of MFC that is not yet widely distributed and is incompatible with Windows XP.

I stumbled across this article while searching for a solution and tried it without any success. I figured that it was because there was no Visual Studio 2010 or older installations on my computer.

[Use newer Visual Studio Version with an older MFC Version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016952/use-newer-visual-studio-version-with-an-older-mfc-version)

Is there a way to compile an MFC application compatible with at least Windows XP on Visual Studio 2012 without any older installations of Visual Studio present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you want is possible, unfortunately. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/06/15/10320645.aspx) article says that there will indeed be XP support this fall when Windows 8 is officially released. But [this](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/products/compatibility) article says that you will need an installation of Visual Studio 2010 as well. My guess is that VS2012 simply doesn't have the capability to support XP, and that the update this fall will just kind of link it to VS2010. There might be some unofficial ways to do it, but it seems as if MS is completely dropping XP support, so you'll probably need VS2010 if you want to develop for it.

Comment: This is unfortunately exactly what I feared. Thanks for the answer. +1 for the links.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick footnote as it were: I have been able to successfully use the newer MFC and newer compilers from vs2010 from visual C++ 6.0. It took a great deal of gutting and swapping, but it is possible at least in this way. Of course I haven't tested it the other way around but it seems like you should be able to, just don't expect it to work perfectly. Also, since visual studio can be customized a great deal with extensions, you could probably make an extension to 'hot swap' libraries, etc. But I assure you, its easier to just use 2008 which isn't missing all that much, esp now with the feature service pack put out by MS to give newer stuff like ribbons, tr1, etc. I've yet to see a reason to move to 2010 or 2012 unless i actually wanted the newer MFC, etc. Which I don't, tried em, hated em, staying at 2008. So the answer is yes, but hacky... and, as above, Microsoft IS breaking off support in 2014 altogether so keep that in mind...even though IMO 2008 is the best version still.